# Anime series about a main character gaining power from blue blob on his arm

Tags: ayakashi

I'm looking for the title of an anime I've watched several years ago (I think the anime should be from 5 to 10 years ago). I don't remember much about it, just a few scenes from the first episodes. I think it was some short anime series (12 to 26 episodes).

I remember the main character getting his power form something like a blue blob that wrapped around his arm (making it somehow looks like Chad's arm from Bleach).

There were also other people getting powers (or weapons I don't remember) in a similar way. In particular I remember a fight with an evil guy in a park who was trying to kill random people there.

The story was set up more or less in the present.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be looking for **[Ayakashi](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=8567)** (2007, 12 episodes).

> Adapted from the 2005 adults-only superhuman battle action visual novel game Ayakashi. Ayakashi is a parasite life force that gives superpowers to its host, taking in return the host's entire life force. Kusaka Yuu is a student that lost his will to live after the death of a dear childhood friend, until the day a mysterious girl, named Yoake Eimu, appears. From that moment on, his life would never be the same again. Hunted by Ayakashi and their hosts, the power within Yuu awakens and a never ending battle begins.

[image: Yuu being OP]

<sup>**Yuu KUSAKA in his OP mode.**</sup>

In episode 2, an evil guy killed many random people in a park and harmed Yuu's classmate in order to provoke him and awaken his powers. He got totally pwned by the enraged protagonist.

Comment: You're welcome :) and good details in the question that allowed me to get it right with little effort.